# Solving an ODE with a sign function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a way to solve differential equations of the form
$$\frac{d^{2}x}{dt^{2}} + x = -\mathrm{sgn}(\frac{dx}{dt})?$$ I've never seen these types of differential equations before and I have no idea how to start.

Comment: Does this come from anywhere in particular? What's the motivation?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the dynamical system

$$
\cases{
\dot x = y\\
\dot y = -\sigma(y)-x
}
$$

where $\sigma(\cdot)$ is the sign function, we have

$$
\cases{
\dot x x = y x\\
\dot y y = -\sigma(y)y - x y
}
$$

adding the odes we have

$$
\frac 12(x^2+y^2) + \int \sigma(y)\dot x dt = C_0
$$

or

$$
x^2+y^2  \pm 2x = 2C_0\Rightarrow y^2+(x\pm 1)^2 = C_1
$$

so in the phase plane we have orbits composed from circles $y^2+(x\pm 1)^2 = C_k$

Considering non null initial conditions as $x_0, y_0$ the first support circle is

$$
\mathcal{C}_1\to y^2+(x+\sigma(y_0))^2=y_0^2+(x_0+\sigma(y_0))^2 = r_1^2
$$

and after that, while $r_k-2\gt 0$ we have

$$
\mathcal{C}_{k+1}\to y^2+(x+\sigma(y_0)^k)^2=r_{k+1}^2,\ \ \ r_{k+1}=r_k-2
$$

Follows a MATHEMATICA script showing this procedure

```
tmax = 20;
x0 = 10;
y0 = -2;
rk = Sqrt[y0^2 + (x0 + Sign[y0])^2];
R = {rk};
xc = -Sign[y0];
GR = {Graphics[{Dashed, Circle[{xc, 0}, rk]}]};
While[rk - 2 >= 0,
  rk = rk - 2;
  AppendTo[R, rk];
  xc = -xc;
  AppendTo[GR, Graphics[{Dashed, Circle[{xc, 0}, rk]}]];
  ];
solx = NDSolve[{x''[t] + Sign[x'[t]] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == x0, x'[0] == y0}, x, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];
xt = x[t] /. solx;
Plot[xt, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}]
solxy = NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] + Sign[y[t]] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];
xyt = {x[t], y[t]} /. solxy;
gr0 = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{x0, y0}]}];
gr2 = ParametricPlot[xyt, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}];
Show[GR, gr0, gr2, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

Follows a plot showing $x(t)$ and after, the phase plane with the support circles in dashed black.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solutions to this ODE are rather interesting. In outline, general solution oscillates with linearly decreasing amplitude until the amplitude decays to zero. If the solution is non-zero at that point it just stops, and cannot be continued to more positive $t$. Otherwise it remains zero for ever.

More precisely, we must construct the solutions piecewise. Each piece covers a part of the solution where $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is either always positive or always negative, or always zero.

- If $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is positive, the equation simplifies to

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + x = -1$$

which has solutions of the form

$$x = A\sin(t-B) - 1$$

for $A>0$. Such a solution covers the range $B - \pi/2 < t < B + \pi/2$.

- Similarly, if $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is negative, the possible solutions have the form

$$x = 1 - A\sin(t-B)$$

If we try to join these up to make a continuous function, we find that the two types of piece must alternate, and that each new piece decreases $A$ by 2 (and increases $B$ by $\pi$). Once $A$ decreases below 2, it is not possible to add on any more pieces, and the solution stops dead.

There is one more case possible: $x = 0$. It is valid for all $t$. It also joins cleanly onto solutions of the other two types if $A = 2$.